# How to have a query with columns needing different conditions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, conditional-statements

For a game, I want to count the number of user sign-ups by hour (using [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).). 
Quite easy, something like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DAY(date_user), HOUR(date_user) 
FROM users, 
GROUP BY DAY(date_user), HOUR(date_user)
```

After that, I want to only take in consideration users which have played the game at least one time. I have a second table with scores.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DAY(date_user), HOUR(date_user) 
FROM users, scores 
WHERE users.id = scores.userid 
GROUP BY DAY(date_user), HOUR(date_user)
```

Great...
Now, I want the two queries to result in one table, like:

```
Global signups | Signups of playing users | Day | Hour
```

I have not found a working query for this yet. Should I use unions? Or joins?

Comment: You should use an explicit join instead of 'SELECT A, B WHERE ...'.

Comment: Is there a reason why you group by hour and day, but not month or year?

Comment: For Hour & Day, it was just a test on a short set of data so it was ok. I'll add months & years after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
select 
    day(date_user)
,   hour(date_user)
,   count(distinct u.id) as GlobalSignups
,   count(distinct s.userid) as SignupsOfPlayingUsers
from users u
left join scores s on u.id = s.userid
group by day(date_user), hour(date_user)
```

Counting distinct user id's gives the total number of users.  When the left join fails, `s.userid` will be `NULL`, and `NULLs` are not counted by `count()`.  So `count(distinct s.userid)` returns the number of users with signups.

Comment: Do you mean 'When the left join fails'?

Comment: Oh, I should probably have refreshed before commenting, sorry. :)